# Output field in autocomplete suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch

when I want to index a document in elasticsearch this problem occurring:

`message [MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[unknown field name [output], must be one of [input, weight, contexts]];]`

I know that the output field removed from elasticsearch in version 5 but why? and what I have to do for getting single result for inputs?

Comment: I've found that the original value is withing the _source field that is returned with the suggestion, but it's not really a solution to use it from there because the key and structure changes based on the original object it originates from.

Answer (score 1):

`output` field removed from ElasticSearch in version 5, now `_source` filed returns with the suggestion. Example shown in below.

**Mapping**

```
{
    "user": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "analyzer": "simple",
                "search_analyzer": "simple"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Abc",
    "suggest":
    {
        "input": "Abc::123"
    },
    "output": "Abc::123"
}
```

**Query**

POST - http://localhost:9200/user*/_suggest?pretty

```
{
"type-suggest": {
    "text": "Abc",
    "completion": {
        "field": "suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elastic mentions the following

> As suggestions are document-oriented, suggestion metadata (e.g. output) should now be specified as a field in the document. The support for specifying output when indexing suggestion entries has been removed. Now suggestion result entry’s text is always the un-analyzed value of the suggestion’s input (same as not specifying output while indexing suggestions in pre-5.0 indices).

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_suggester.html)

## Update

I was able to get a single output from multiple inputs in ES 5.1.1. You can find the answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423902/whats-a-good-alternative-for-the-output-field-in-elasticsearch-5-1-completion-s/41761370#41761370)